# Using ICollection in Rest API Controllers to get specific Data

Tags: api, asp.net-core, routes, dbcontext, icollection

So I'm building my first Rest API and I have those 3 Model classes.
[image: Desk Model]

[image: Person Model]

[image: Booking Model]

And here is my DbContext

[image: DbContext]

Now I want to do this: I want to create a GET Method in the DeskController that shows me every Desk where bookings = null. I tried to construct it myself but I have problems with the error message "Unsupported Media Type" when I try to reach the route.

[image: DeskController]

Comment: What is do  you want  the `Person booking`  stand in for  ?

Comment: I just tried to solve my problem. I don't really know how to implement the ICollection into the GET Method.

Comment: If is your first time using a Rest Api you should start for the beggining, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) this is a web api tutorial (similar to rest api). To improve after the tutorial use Guid's in Id's and the final steps is adding more models and connect all. I think the problem may be in the controller (if isnt maybe in the UI / View) the HTTPGet should return a book with that id correct (if exists) correct? If yes, look the tutorial and check differences. Hope I help you with your first Rest Api

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I'll look into the tutorial.

Comment: @Joshua Do you mean you want to get the ICollection<Person> Booking in Get action?